# Linq to Entities complexity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm starting with Linq to entities and maybe someone could shed some light.

I have two tables - `Vizite` (parent table) and `AngajatiVizite` (child table). I'm using Database first, so I have created the relationship between them using Vizite.Id and AngajatiVizite.IdVizita.

I need to get the rows from `Vizite` and one more bit field which must be 0 if the `DataStart` or `DataEnd` fields are null or count of child records from `AngajatiVizite` is zero. That's it, if the `Vizite` has zero subordinate records or any of those `Data####` fields is null, the calculated field is 0.

So far so good, the linq I'm using works properly. The syntax I have used is this one:

```
 var list = ctx.Vizite
                .OrderBy(p => p.DataEnd != null && p.DataStart != null && p.AngajatiVizite.Count > 0)
                .ThenBy(p => p.Data)
                .Select(p => new
                {
                    p.Id,
                    p.Numar,
                    p.Data,
                    p.DataStart,
                    p.DataEnd,
                    Programat = p.DataEnd != null && p.DataStart != null && p.AngajatiVizite.Count > 0
                })
                .ToList();
```

The sql command generated by Linq is extremely complex and I don't understand why it has to be *that* complex and what's the difference.

What I'm getting from linq is this:

```
SELECT 
[Project6].[Numar] AS [Numar], 
[Project6].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project6].[Data] AS [Data], 
[Project6].[DataStart] AS [DataStart], 
[Project6].[DataEnd] AS [DataEnd], 
[Project6].[C2] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project5].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project5].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project5].[Numar] AS [Numar], 
    [Project5].[Data] AS [Data], 
    [Project5].[DataStart] AS [DataStart], 
    [Project5].[DataEnd] AS [DataEnd], 
    CASE WHEN ([Project5].[C2] > 0) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ([Project5].[C3] > 0)) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project4].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project4].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Project4].[Numar] AS [Numar], 
        [Project4].[Data] AS [Data], 
        [Project4].[DataStart] AS [DataStart], 
        [Project4].[DataEnd] AS [DataEnd], 
        [Project4].[C2] AS [C2], 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[AngajatiVizite] AS [Extent5]
            WHERE [Project4].[Id] = [Extent5].[IdVizita]) AS [C3]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [Project3].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Project3].[Numar] AS [Numar], 
            [Project3].[Data] AS [Data], 
            [Project3].[DataStart] AS [DataStart], 
            [Project3].[DataEnd] AS [DataEnd], 
            (SELECT 
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[AngajatiVizite] AS [Extent4]
                WHERE [Project3].[Id] = [Extent4].[IdVizita]) AS [C2]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                CASE WHEN ([Project2].[C1] > 0) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ([Project2].[C2] > 0)) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1], 
                [Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
                [Project2].[Numar] AS [Numar], 
                [Project2].[Data] AS [Data], 
                [Project2].[DataStart] AS [DataStart], 
                [Project2].[DataEnd] AS [DataEnd]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                    [Project1].[Numar] AS [Numar], 
                    [Project1].[Data] AS [Data], 
                    [Project1].[DataStart] AS [DataStart], 
                    [Project1].[DataEnd] AS [DataEnd], 
                    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
                    (SELECT 
                        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                        FROM [dbo].[AngajatiVizite] AS [Extent3]
                        WHERE [Project1].[Id] = [Extent3].[IdVizita]) AS [C2]
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                        [Extent1].[Numar] AS [Numar], 
                        [Extent1].[Data] AS [Data], 
                        [Extent1].[DataStart] AS [DataStart], 
                        [Extent1].[DataEnd] AS [DataEnd], 
                        (SELECT 
                            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                            FROM [dbo].[AngajatiVizite] AS [Extent2]
                            WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[IdVizita]) AS [C1]
                        FROM [dbo].[Vizite] AS [Extent1]
                    )  AS [Project1]
                )  AS [Project2]
            )  AS [Project3]
        )  AS [Project4]
    )  AS [Project5]
)  AS [Project6]
```

when all I needed was actually this:

```
Select
Vizite.Id
, Vizite.Numar
, Vizite.Data
, Vizite.DataStart
, Vizite.DataEnd
, Case
    When DataStart != Null And DataEnd != Null And (Select Count(Id) From AngajatiVizite Where Vizite.Id = AngajatiVizite.IdVizita) > 0 Then 1
    Else 0
End As Programat
From Vizite
Order By Programat, Data
```

Can anyone please explain to me why the generated SQL is that complex that's even almost impossible to figure it out by simply reading the sql syntax?

Thank you

Comment: It is that complexw because you are using logic into your linq-to-entities Select. If you do that then EF wil generate generally a SQL Subquery rather than CASE clause.

Comment: @CodeNotFound: could you please give me an alternative idea? I'm beginner and struggling with this. Is there a better way to do it? (besides calling a stored procedure, which I'm actually doing right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't build handsome queries, that's a fact; and it's a nuisance sometimes, because it can be really hard to trace SQL logging back to LINQ statements.

It would be a *problem* though, if the query plan optimizer wouldn't know how to handle them. Fortunately, when Sql Server is concerned, the EF team has managed to make SQL better optimizable in each release since EF5. So *generally* you shouldn't worry about it too much and only start looking into it when performance is worse than can reasonably be expected.

There are some rules of the thumb though. One of them is to calculate computed values only once. This is where the `let` keyword comes in handy:

```
var list = (from p in ctx.Vizite
            let Programat = p.DataEnd != null && p.DataStart != null
                         && p.AngajatiVizite.Count > 0
            order by Programat, p.Data
            select new
            {
                p.Id,
                p.Numar,
                p.Data,
                p.DataStart,
                p.DataEnd,
                Programat
            }).ToList();
```

This works well in LINQ query syntax. In fluent (method) syntax you can do the exact same thing, but that requires two subsequent `Select` statements.

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone. Your answers were very helpful to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

What happens to the complexity of your SQL statement if you do the following?

```
var list = ctx.Vizite
    .Select(p => new
    {
        p.Id,
        p.Numar,
        p.Data,
        p.DataStart,
        p.DataEnd,
        Programat =
            p.DataEnd != null && p.DataStart != null && p.AngajatiVizite.Count > 0
    }
    .OrderBy(p => p.Programat)
    .ThenBy(p => p.Data)
    .ToList();
```

My hope is that by not repeating `p.DataEnd != null && p.DataStart != null && p.AngajatiVizite.Count > 0` and moving the `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` after the select, you'll get a simpler query.

---

**Edit**

To potentially simplify the SQL even further, you could opt to do some of the work after obtaining the raw data from the database:

```
var list = ctx.Vizite
    .Select(p => new
    {
        p.Id,
        p.Numar,
        p.Data,
        p.DataStart,
        p.DataEnd,
        AngajatiViziteCount = p.AngajatiVizite.Count
    }
    .AsEnumerable() // do the rest of the work using LINQ to objects
    .OrderBy(p => p.DataEnd != null && p.DataStart != null && p.AngajatiViziteCount > 0)
    .ThenBy(p => p.Data)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping :)

Indeed, the resulting sql is less complex, but still too complex, IMO. It has  SELECT FROM SELECT FROM SELECT FROM SELECT with two more SELECTs in the fields list....

 I can't paste it here because the comment field is limited to 500 chars :(

Comment: @GrigoreDolghin, I edited my answer with another idea to try. If you're looking for a place to paste in the long SQL statements, I recommend you edit your question and add any new content to the end.